# /I want to show a messagebox when the right excel file is not selected

Tags: excel, vba

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim currentWorkbook    As Excel.Workbook
    Dim otherWorkbook     As Excel.Workbook
    Dim workbookName      As Variant

    Set currentWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
    workbookName = Application.GetOpenFilename(workbookNamePath)


    If Not workbookName = False Then
        Set otherWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(workbookName)
        Workbooks("name.csv").Sheets("sheet 2").Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
            otherWorkbook.Close False
        Set otherWorkbook = Nothing
    End If

    MsgBox "done?", Title:="Name", Buttons:=vbInformation
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 End Sub
```

**so when I select a different file other than name.csv i want to give a message " Select the right file" rather than giving me an error code. I am new to vba please help

Comment: Welcome to SO. What does the error message say? Which line is causing it? I guess `workbookNamePath` is a string. It needs to be declared as such and a value needs to be assigned to it.

Comment: Why would you want people to select a file, if there is only one file they should be opening? You could just open it for them right?

Comment: I asked the same question to my boss man! He was like you know people can select wrong file so....

Answer (score 0):

@Luuklag is absolutely right. Formally I'd check the filename before opening it like this:

```
If Not workbookName = False Then
    if mid(workbookname, instrrev(workbookname,"\")+1) <> "name.csv" Then
         MsgBox "Select the right file...."
    End If
```

`GetOpenFileName` returns the full path so you can even check the path.